# Allocating memory by using Malloc (char & int)

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I'm new to `C` , and I'm trying to understand `malloc`. 
I'm trying to create a program that assigns memory for cards/colors and print them out.

I've made a function that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ACE 1;
#define CardSize 52
#define colors 4

int main() {
    count();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void count() {
    int *cards;
    int i, j, f;
    char *color[4] = { "Diamond", "Heart", "Spade", "Clubs"};
    cards = malloc(CardSize * sizeof(int));
    *color = malloc(colors * sizeof(char)); //Here's where my program crashes
    for (f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            cards[i] = (i % 13) + 1;
            printf("%d of %s\n", cards[i], color[f]);
        }
    }
}
```

Without the line `*color = malloc(colors*sizeof(char));` the program works fine, but I want to allocate memory for my colors.

The output is this:

```
1 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
2 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
3 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
4 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
5 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
6 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
7 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
8 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
9 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
10 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
11 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
12 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
13 of ════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²╬─Ép┐p
```

Which should be diamonds, then the rest is printed out fine, 1 of hearts, 2 of hearts, etc and all the other colors.

Please can you help me understand where I'm making the mistake, and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Delete the line that crashes.

Comment: Aside: although you don't use `ACE` yet, you should probably remove the `;` at the end of `#define ACE 1;`

Comment: Why do you need to allocate and assign another memory while there are already (pointers to first elements of) string literals assigned? `malloc()` doesn't initialize allocated memory, so the `printf()` will print randam data, and maybe cause Segmentation Fault if there isn't terminating null character before what you cannot read. What do you want to do?

Comment: What do you expect  `*color = malloc(colors*sizeof(char));` to do?

Comment: You already allocated memory for the colour names.  Why do you want to allocate more memory? Especially in light of your comment " i just wanted to specificly store just the amount of memory that was necessary."

Answer (score 2):

You define `color` to be an array of 4 pointers to `char` arrays that you initialize correctly:

```
char *color[4] = { "Diamon", "Heart", "Spade", "Clubs"};
```

But you immediately store another pointer in the first element of this array:

```
*color = malloc(colors*sizeof(char)); //Here's where my program crashes
```

You should not do that at all.  I don't really understand your intention in doing so, but just remove this line and your program will behave correctly.
Note that string literals are stored in read only memory, so `color` should really be defined as:

```
const char *color[4] = { "Diamon", "Heart", "Spade", "Clubs" };
```

Also fix the typo on `Diamond`, `Hearts` and `Spades`. Indeed the suits are plural except `Diamond`.

The value for card should probably be computed differently, as a number from `0` to `51`.  Also `cards` should be returned or freed if you do not use it. The code would be changed this way:

```
void count(void) {
    int *cards = malloc(CardSize * sizeof(int));
    int i, j, f;
    const char *color[4] = { "Diamond", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs" };

    for (i = 0; i < CardSize; i++) {
        j = (i % 13) + 1;  // Card value
        f = (i / 13) % 4;  // color number 0 to 3
        cards[i] = i % 52;
        printf("%d of %s\n", j, color[f]);
    }
    free(cards);
}
```

Comment: But really, why do you use f = (i / 13) % 4; , cant you just skip that line, the output will be the same if you'll do it my way anyways?

Thank you for replying! But, the reason why i wanted to use malloc is that i just wanted to specificly store just the amount of memory that was necessary. By the way, when im going to shuffle my deck, can i still use the same variables from the count() function?

Comment: @Williamhart: I should have written `f = (i % 52) / 4;`.  The reason I do this is for the `count` function to work even if you are dealing more than `52` cards.  Your version uses the implied assumption that `CardSize == 52`.  If you modify the `#define` for some reason, the code will either deal too many cards and access memory beyond the allocated amount or fail to deal more than 52 cards.

Comment: Implied assumptions, especially involving explicit constants is bad practice.  They often cause errors, especially when modifying a program to extend functionality. Try and avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

These extra allocations are for nothing but exercise, but try this.

```
void count() {
    int *cards;
    int i, j, f;
    const char *color_data[4] = { "Diamon", "Heart", "Spade", "Clubs"};
    char **color;
    cards = malloc(CardSize*sizeof(int));
    color = malloc(colors*sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        color[i] = malloc((strlen(color_data[i]) + 1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(color[i], color_data[i]);
    }
    for (f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            cards[i] = (i % 13) + 1;
            printf("%d of %s\n", cards[i], color[f]);
        }
    }
    free(cards);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        free(color[i]);
    }
    free(color);
}
```

Notes:

- Add `#include <string.h>` to the head of your code to use `strlen()` and `strcpy()`.
- Omitted here, the return values of `malloc()` should be checked for not being `NULL`.
- Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` (=1) means nothing, but I kept it for not losing readability.
- Avoid memory leaks. Use `free()` for memories allocated via `malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you for replying!

But, the reason why i wanted to use malloc is that i just wanted to specificly store just the amount of memory that was necessary.

By the way, when im going to shuffle my deck, can i still use the same variables from the count() function?

Comment: What do you mean? You bring back no variables from `count()` so far. If you implement shuffle in `count()`, yes, you can use these variables, but then the name `count` will be confusing.